# Библиотека календаря под андроид

Tags: android, java

Какую библиотеку можно использовать для календаря, красивую и изящную?

Где-то я видел такую статью про изящный календарь под андроид, но не смог ее найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все ресурсы, для андройда, лежат обычно в одном месте - [github](https://github.com/). А вот и календари [тык](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Calendar.md)(стоит учесть лицензии). Так же можно поискать в [арсенале](https://android-arsenal.com/), но опять же - все ресурсы с [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: @nuclominus я не понял с лицензиями там есть MIt и apachelicense2, они оба как бы бесплатные и можно использовать как угодно, что там смотреть то в лицензиях есть ли какие то подводные камни в этих лицензияъ